# Переход с apache на nginx

Tags: nginx, php-nginx, plesk

Всем привет, столкнулся с проблемой:
Есть сервер с установленной панелью plesk.
Раньше работало на апаче проксируемом nginx'ом, сейчас пытаюсь перейти на полностью nginx. 
В связи с этим необходимо заменить htaccess конфигурацией nginx, и вот тут как оказалось собака зарыта: а) плеск не даёт редактировать конфиг напрямую, только дописывать правила в специальном разделе; б) в сети нет ни одного внятного обьяснения как писать конфиги для nginx'а, а к большинству моих вопросов аналогичных уже заданным на аналогичных sof сайтов ответы в духе "проблема д****о подумай головой и всё получится".
Ниже бывший .htaccess:

```
# Редирект с index на main
DirectoryIndex main.php
# HTTP to HTTPS
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
# Убрать .php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
#редиректы
ErrorDocument 404 https://site.ru/error
ErrorDocument 403 https://site.ru/error
ErrorDocument 401 https://site.ru/error
ErrorDocument 500 https://site.ru/error
```

Буду очень благодарен, если кто-то напишет как это сделать в nginx и совсем благодарен - если с объяснениями.

Для "убрать .php" было методом домыслов и размышлений было написано:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri /$uri.php;
}
```

(в коде все ссылки без .php)
Теоретически это помогло, но судя по всё тем же бесподобным ответам на аналогичные моим вопросы из за этого невозможно задать страницы ошибок.

Также буду благодарен, если кто-то подскажет как правильно задать хранение шрифтов, сейчас это:

```
location ~*.(woff2|woff|ttf|svg)$ {
    expires max;
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
}
```

Однако почему-то постоянно один или два шрифта (всего 3 и 1 .svg) вместо max сохраняются на 4 часа.

p.s. если необходимо посмотреть где это применяется на практике: iccmiu.ru/main (с main, потому что замена index на main мне так и не далась)))). )
p.s. (2) https://vk.cc/adrisn тут автоматически собираемый панелькой конфиг сайта про который написано выше

UPD: 
Для замены индекса на main сработало:

```
location ~ /$ {
        index "main.html" "main.cgi" "main.pl" "main.php" "main.xhtml" "main.htm" "main.shtml";
    }
```

Правда указывать это пришлось в самой панели в настройках отключённого апача , надеюсь кому-то поможет мой опыт, остались страницы ошибок.

UPD 2: 
Уже собирался выставить на конкурс, но проблема с страницами решилась при помощи:

```
fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
error_page 401 403 404 500 502 503 /error;
```

Всё так же надеюсь кому-то окажется полезным мой опыт в решении вышеописанных проблем, к слову благодаря переходу на nginx + fpm, с которого всё и началось pagespeed вырос с 95 до 100, и хотя с данным конкретным сайтом игра не стоила свеч, думаю использование данных конкретных костылей во всех дальнейших случаях всё же оправдает затраченное время.

UPD 3 (Уже даже после успеха):
В upd 2 было найдено решение проблемы с страницей ошибки, которое, однако само привело к ошибке. Дело в том, что страница error.php у меня находится в корневой директории сайта и когда мы воодим допустим site.ru/fdsvfsf (несуществующая страница), он верно показывает страницу ошибок со всем контентом (картинки, видео), однако при открытии допустим site.ru/efwef/efswe (также несуществующий адрес) он хоть и открывает страницу ошибки из корневой директории, теряет ссылки на контент в коде (картинки, видео).
Поэтому для страниц ошибок используем полный URL, в моём конкретном случае это

```
fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
error_page 401 403 404 500 502 503 https:/site.ru/error;
```

И ещё обновление, скоро блог можно будет вести: 
Для замены ссылки с site.ru/something.php на site.ru/something используем

```
location / {
    try_files $uri /$uri.php?$args;
}
```

А не то что было раньше, в предыдущей конфигурации не работает GET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос решился своими силами, см. апдейты.